# How to get protractor suggestions in visual studio?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, protractor, visual-studio-code

when I click control space after writing some characters in a keyword,  I am not getting suggestions from protractor API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [Protractor Snippets](https://github.com/deerawan/vscode-protractor-snippets) extension.